# ¿Por qué no funciona change, click o focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas pues estoy teniendo un problema que no entiendo, estoy haciendo una pequeña funcion en jquery para cambiar el color de borde de un input/select cuando hago click en un elemento (igual me funcionaria que se active solo al hacer focus o si cambia el valor)

```
 $("input").change(function(){
   $(this).style.boder = "1px solid black";
 });
```

probe literalmente con change, con click, con focus, con focusin y la funcion no hace absolutamente nada, que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: podrías darnos el código completo? cual es el input que deseas cambiar? Además, está mal escrito la propiedad que deseas cambiar, es `border`

Comment: serian todos los input en general y bueno gracias por lo de la propiedad no lo habia notado pero probe con alert tambien y no lo muestra

Answer (score 0):

No funciona por un par de cuestiones:

- Tenes que usar la funcion `keyup` si queres detectar cuando teclees, o `focus` si queres hacerlo en el momento que hagas click en el input. `change` espera que hagas un cambio en el input y luego salgas de él, para ejecutarse
- Tenes que usar `this` en lugar de `$this`
- No se si te ocurre pero en el editor de stackoverflow me aparece un `outline` azul cada vez que me paro sobre el input, por lo que lo escondi con `css` para que esto no tape el borde

```js
$("input").focus(function(){
   this.style.border = "1px solid red";
 });
```

```css
input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>
```

**De todas maneras podes hacer lo que queres sin usar `javascript` ni `jquery`, con `css` alcanza**, es mas performante y ademas cuando salis del input se vuelve a cambiar el css, cosa que a mi gusto queda mejor.

```css
 input:focus{
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
 }
```

```html
  <input type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vincule un controlador de eventos al evento de JavaScript "change" o active ese evento en un elemento.

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
   $(this).css('border', '1px solid black')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es hacer el cambio de tu input al dar **click**, tendrías que usar el método `click` de jquery:

```
$("input").click(function(){
   //...
}
```

Ahora solo faltaría cambiar el estilo del input cuando le das click a ello, yo lo hice de esta forma y me funcionó correctamente:

```
$("input").click(function(){
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid black");
});
```

El código completo sería así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Mi campo: <input type="text">
</body>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $("input").click(function () {
        $(this).css("border", "1px solid black");
      });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: nada probe el codigo pero no funciona

Comment: Por ello mismo te solicitaba que adjuntes tu código completo. Además debería funcionarte (a menos que el error se encuentre en otra parte), nos avisas.